# How does MessageQueue.BeginReceive work and how to use it correctly?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, msmq, message-queue

I currently have a background thread. In this thread is a infinite loop.

This loop once in a while updates some values in a database, and then listens 1 second on the MessageQueue (with `queue.Receive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))` ).

As long as no message comes in, this call then internally throws a MessageQueueException (Timeout) which is caught and then the loop continues. If there is a message the call normally returns and the message is processed, after which the loop continues.

This leads to a *lot* of First chance exceptions (every second, except there is a message to process) and this spams the debug output and also breaks in the debugger when I forgot to exclude MessageQueueExceptions.

So how is the async handling of the MessageQueue meant to be done correctly, while still ensuring that, as long as my application runs, the queue is monitored and the database is updated too once in a while. Of course the thread here should not use up 100% CPU.

I just need the big picture or a hint to some correctly done async processing.

Comment: By the sounds of it, the scenario of there being no message coming in is not an exceptional circumstance, in which case throwing an exception seems like a design smell.

Comment: Yes, can't you just return null or default if there is nothing to do, throwing an exception just to avoid returning from a method is a bit crap.

Comment: The MessageQueue class itself is throwing the exception, when the timeout occurs, not me. That is my problem with this solution and what's disturbing me.

Comment: The timeout exception is how MSMQ was designed to work. Do you have to poll the queue every second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered a [MessageEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messageenumerator.aspx) which is returned from the [MessageQueue.GetMessageEnumerator2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.getmessageenumerator2.aspx) ?

- You get a dynamic content of the queue to examine and remove messages from a queue during the iteration.
- If there are no messages then `MoveNext()` will return false and you don't need to catch first-chance exceptions
- If there are new messages after you started iteration then they will be iterated over (if they are put after a cursor).
- If there are new messages before a cursor then you can just reset an iterator or continue (if you don't need messages with lower priority at the moment).

Comment: Yes, thanks. This is great. So I can wait for 1 sec. and if there is no message it just returns false and I can leave the rest of my logic as it is. No more exceptions :)

Answer (score 5):

Rather than looping in a thread, I would recommend registering a delegate for the ReceiveCompleted event of your MessageQueue, as described here:

using System;
using System.Messaging;

namespace MyProject
{
    /// 
    /// Provides a container class for the example.
    /// 
    public class MyNewQueue
    {

```
    //**************************************************
    // Provides an entry point into the application.
    //       
    // This example performs asynchronous receive operation
    // processing.
    //**************************************************

    public static void Main()
    {
        // Create an instance of MessageQueue. Set its formatter.
        MessageQueue myQueue = new MessageQueue(".\\myQueue");
        myQueue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[]
            {typeof(String)});

        // Add an event handler for the ReceiveCompleted event.
        myQueue.ReceiveCompleted += new 
            ReceiveCompletedEventHandler(MyReceiveCompleted);

        // Begin the asynchronous receive operation.
        myQueue.BeginReceive();

        // Do other work on the current thread.

        return;
    }


    //**************************************************
    // Provides an event handler for the ReceiveCompleted
    // event.
    //**************************************************

    private static void MyReceiveCompleted(Object source, 
        ReceiveCompletedEventArgs asyncResult)
    {
        // Connect to the queue.
        MessageQueue mq = (MessageQueue)source;

        // End the asynchronous Receive operation.
        Message m = mq.EndReceive(asyncResult.AsyncResult);

        // Display message information on the screen.
        Console.WriteLine("Message: " + (string)m.Body);

        // Restart the asynchronous Receive operation.
        mq.BeginReceive();

        return; 
    }
}
```

}

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.messaging.messagequeue.receivecompleted?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: link is dead.. yes.. people are still using bloody MSMQ :( And also if you thinking of handling/ throttling the amount of messages this becomes really difficult to work with

Comment: Updated the answer with code extract and link to source

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to the comment by Jamie Dixon, the scenario IS exceptional. Note the naming of the method and its parameters: BeginReceive(TimeSpan timeout)

Had the method been named BeginTryReceive, it would've been perfectly normal if no message was received. Naming it BeginReceive (or Receive, for the sync version) implies that a message is expected to enter the queue. That the TimeSpan parameter is named timeout is also significant, because a timeout IS exceptional. A timeout means that a response was expected, but none was given, and the caller chooses to stop waiting and assumes that an error has occured. When you call BeginReceive/Receive with a 1 second timeout, you are stating that if no message has entered the queue by that time, something must have gone wrong and we need to handle it.

The way I would implement this, if I understand what you want to do correctly, is this:

- Call BeginReceive either with a very large timeout, or even without a timeout if I don't see an empty queue as an error.
- Attach an event handler to the ReceiveCompleted event, which 1) processes the message, and 2) calls BeginReceive again.
- I would NOT use an infinite loop. This is both bad practice and completely redundant when using asynchronous methods like BeginReceive.
- **edit:** To abandon a queue which isn't being read by any client, have the queue writers peek into the queue to determine if it is 'dead'.

**edit:** I have another suggestion. Since I don't know the details of your application I have no idea if it is either feasible or appropriate. It seems to me that you're basically establishing a connection between client and server, with the message queue as the communication channel. Why is this a 'connection'? Because the queue won't be written to if no one is listening. That's pretty much what a connection is, I think. Wouldn't it be more appropriate to use sockets or named pipes to transfer the messages? That way, the clients simply close the Stream objects when they are done reading, and the servers are immediately notified. As I said, I don't know if it can work for what you're doing, but it feels like a more appropriate communication channel.

Comment: As stated previously in my question, it is important to update a table in the database once in a while to tell other applications that the listener is still alive. So when waiting indefinetly for a message, the table will not be updated, the client is considered dead and will not be targeted for messages anymore. But it is important that the client gets messages that are sent. So it is important to have both the listening for messages _and_ the constant update of the table in one logical concern.

Comment: As I said: In the table are all active target queues. When a queue wasn't updated for a certain amount of time, it is considered dead and will be removed from the table. When a message is sent, it is sent to all active queues.

Comment: OK. I couldn't find where you wrote that. Anyway, another way to do it (better if you ask me) is to let the queue writers determine when a queue is dead by peeking into it to see if messages are removed from the queue by clients.

Comment: No, its not a 'connection'. It's simply a notification. The sender (a client, possibly the same code running on another machine but possibly also a service running elsewhere) needs to notify all clients (including himself) of certain events. In this case it looks for all active clients in the DB and sends the message in their queues. Then clients then can (but don't need to) process the message. Sockets would require a LOT of connections between all running instances to notify all other clients and consume a lot more resources.